# Double-Substitutions in First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\phi$ be a first-order formula, and let $\phi_t^x$ be the formula $\phi$ with term $t$ substituted for variable $x$.

Exercise 6 in section 1.8 of Leary and Kristiansen’s *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic* asks when $(\phi_y^x)_x^y$ is $\phi$. The solution says: if and only if $y$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$.

Is this not wrong? If $\phi$ is $\forall x(x=y)$, then $y$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$, but $(\phi_y^x)_x^y$ is $\forall x (x = x)$. Shouldn’t the condition include that $x$ be substitutable for $y$ in $\phi$ as well?

Comment: $(\phi_y^x)_x^y$ is $\forall x(x=x),$ but that is still a counterexample.

Comment: Oops! Corrected.

Comment: The most obvious source of problems here is that $y$ cannot be free in $\phi$... does their definition of "substitutible" somehow preclude that?

Comment: I think these two will do it: $y$ is not free in $\phi$ and y is substitutable for $x$ (the definition of substitutable I'm using is that a substitution of $y$ for each free occurrence of $x$ does not result in $y$ being captured by any quantifiers).

Comment: Agreed! I just came to the same conclusion. I don’t see anything in the book’s definition of substitutability that precludes $y$ being free in $\phi$, so I think it’s just a mistake. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not connected to quantification: $Py$ is a counterexample as well since $((Py)^x_y)^y_x = Px$. The solution should be: $y$ not part of $\phi$; therefore $((\phi)^x_y)^y_x = \phi$. Proof: Induction on terms then on formulas.